# Does English have a way to distinguish between a 12-hour "day" a 24-hour "day"?

Tags: ambiguity

I've always found this highly frustrating; to not be able to unambiguously refer to a "full" "day" (24 hours) and a "day" which is also a "half full day" (12 hours). There is a lot of difference between "waiting for a day" and "waiting for a day", or "half a day" as in 6 hours versus 12.

Why, in spite of all the problems this must have caused over the centuries, did they never invent a word for a "full day"? Or did they?

Comment: Who uses a 12-hour "day"?

Comment: Context is always important. Your "day" of twelve hours is more _day-as-contrasted-with-night_ rather than _day-as-a-formal-temporal-interval_. Generally, when one "waits for a day", it refers to the formal temporal interval, or, more colloquially, "Try again tomorrow at about this same time". Admittedly "half a day" can be a little more ambiguous, but many native speakers of English - or at least AmE in the NYC area - seem to realize this, and will say things like "try again this afternoon/evening" rather than "wait half a day".

Comment: There is  daytime if you want to roughly  refer to the 12hours portion of the day.

Comment: Saying "I waited half the day" is usually unambiguous, as is "I waited all day". There is generally no confusion with "I waited a day".

Comment: This ambiguity is not peculiar to English.

Comment: What language or culture are you trying to impose on English? In general words appear in languages to describe objects, ideas etc. that exist in a society that speaks the language.  I presume that the Australian Aborigines didn’t have a word for wheel.

Comment: @David, people in English-speaking cultures do have two distinct **concepts** that are both expressed by the same word, *day*. This is reflected by their being listed in dictionaries as distinct (although related) meanings of the word. If the language developed so that different words came to carry these two meanings, that would not be an imposition on these cultures from something outside them.

Comment: @jsw29 — ? Are you talking about “daytime”, as opposed to “nighttime”? Or the 24 hour clock? Or what? Daytime is only 12 hours on the equator (or something of the sort).

Comment: @David, I am referring to the two concepts that the question seems to be about: day in the sense of the period, roughly, between dawn and dusk, and day in the sense of the period of 24 hours. I am assuming that the OP's reference to 12 hours is not to be taken strictly, but as a way of articulating the former concept (see Hachi's comment), because the question treats both meanings as the meanings that the word actually has in English.

Comment: @jsw29 — In which case the poster is incorrect. English differentiates between “day” and “daytime”. However it does not make a distinction between jour and journee, as in French. A case of linguistic differences that have no simple explanation (as to why one language makes the distinction and another not), but which those learning foreign languages soon encounter and must accept.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a 12-hour day expressed in the question is unclear to me, and the poster does not say in which language this distinction is made. However, on the assumption that the 12-hour day represents the hours of light, this is expressed in English as:

> [**daytime**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/daytime)
>
> “the time during which there is daylight” (Merriam-Webster)

and

> [**daylight hours**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/daylight-hours)
>
> “the hours when it is daylight” (Collins)

*As for an explanation for the lack of a completely different word…*

I could imagine there being a specific term for this in say, Arabic, because that language is spoken at latitudes where the daylight and hours of darkness are roughly equal. In Britain, in contrast these vary markedly between summer and winter, especially in Scotland.

It is also possible that, because the concept of daylight hours has religious significance (for Ramadan) in Muslim countries, a specific word would develop. There is no such significance in Christian countries, abstinence from certain foods being undertaken at particular periods of the year or on particular days.